# I cannot transfer the list/dictionary into my test library in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I wanna to transfer one list as parameter into my library keyword:

```
ModifyDefaultValue
    ${DataJson}    ModifyDefaultValue    ${DataJson}    @{vargs}
```

And the @vargs list is combined with string and List:

```
@{vargs} Create List NO=1227003021    requestType=0    destination=@{destinations}
```

In my library:

```
def ModifyDefaultValue(self, dictOri, *vargs):
    '''<br/>
        *vargs: List Tyep and format is: var1=value1, var2=value2
    '''
    logger.info("SmartComLibrary ModifyDefaultValue()", also_console=True)
    for i in range(len(vargs)):
        logger.info("\t----Type: %s" % str(vargs[i].split("=")[1].__class__))
```

They always are:

```
20160630 22:11:07.501 :  INFO :     ----Type: <type 'unicode'>
```

But i wanna the "destination" should be "list".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create list will create a list of 3 strings no matter what you put after destination= below.

```
Create List NO=1227003021    requestType=0    destination=@{destinations}
```

It looks like you are manually trying to use keyword arguments. But Python and Robot Framework support them so there is no need to parse and split on '=', etc. Change your keyword to accept keyword arguments. Then instead of building a list, you build a dictionary.

```
    def ModifyDefaultValue(self, dictOri, **kwargs):
        logger.info("SmartComLibrary ModifyDefaultValue()", also_console=True)
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            logger.info("\t----Type: %s: %s" % (k, type(v)))
```

In your test:

```
${destinations}    Create List    a    b    c
&{kwargs}    Create Dictionary    NO=1227003021    requestType=0    destination=${destinations}
ModifyDefaultValue    asdf    &{kwargs}    # note the & here
```

Output:

```
20160630 12:12:41.923 :  INFO :     ----Type: requestType: <type 'unicode'>
20160630 12:12:41.923 :  INFO :     ----Type: destination: <type 'list'>
20160630 12:12:41.923 :  INFO :     ----Type: NO: <type 'unicode'>
```

Alternatively, you could also have ModifyDefaultValue take a dict as the second argument.

```
def ModifyDefaultValue(self, dictOri, args):
    logger.info("SmartComLibrary ModifyDefaultValue()", also_console=True)
    for k, v in args.items():
        logger.info("\t----Type: %s: %s" % (k, type(v)))
```

In your data:

```
${destinations}    Create List    a    b    c
&{args}    Create Dictionary    NO=1227003021    requestType=0    destination=${destinations}
ModifyDefaultValue    asdf    ${args}    # note the $ here
```

See also:

- http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#free-keyword-arguments
- http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#free-keyword-arguments-kwargs